# Gulp giving error on symlinks in gulp.src()

Tags: javascript, osx-mavericks, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I have a symlink in my images folder that points to another folder containing external images provided by a third party library (managed by bower - gotta love javascript). As part of my build process, I compress all images as follows:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
return gulp.src('static/img/**/*')
    .pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
});
```

When gulp gets to the symbolic link folder in the img folder, it returns

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: EISDIR, read
```

Using gulp-debug shows that it baulks on the symlink folder. I am on Mac OSX and the symlink was created using ln -s. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the actual file / folder instead of the symlink? Just to verify that symlinks are indead the problem. The EISDIR error makes me think that gulp is trying to use a directory as it's src instead of the files in that directory.

Comment: Works fine when it is a folder. I've used this as a temporary solution.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue presently working with JSPM local links...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gulp.src()` uses [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob), which doesn't crawl symlinks:

> `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

> Note that symlinked directories are not crawled as part of a `**`, though their contents may match against subsequent portions of the pattern. This prevents infinite loops and duplicates and the like.

I don't know if it's supposed to error or just skip them.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem when pointing to a `symlink` folder.
The solution was simple, just used [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs) package.

```
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');

gulp.task('myTask', [], function() {
  vfs.src('static/img/**/*')
  .pipe(vfs.dest('dist/img'))
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option 'follow: true' to make Gulp follow symlinks. For example:

```
gulp.src('static/img/**/*', { follow: true })
```